# Do Eager Loading affects performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've used eager loading since lazy loading is not loading all the relevant data before object dispose. Do eager loading give performance issue ?

So when to use these two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading by definition only loads data when referenced so "works as supposed to" and all data would not be loaded before a container object is disposed. When the data must be there eager loading is used, but data must be constrained to just the required data otherwise a performance hit occurs in fetching and formatting data ( if required ) this can be mitigated with paging.